# авторизация пользователя на сервере и получение его роли в приложении

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework

Пишу приложение на C# с применением WPF и Entity Framework. Необходимо сделать авторизацию пользователя и, в зависимости от его роли, отобразить доступный ему функционал.
С отображением все понятно, но как сделать авторизацию и получение роли?
вот такие роли будут в системе:

```
           //Создаем логины
        context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("CREATE LOGIN BakeryAdmin WITH PASSWORD = 'Admin' CREATE LOGIN BakeryManager WITH PASSWORD = 'Manager' CREATE LOGIN BakeryUser WITH PASSWORD = 'User'");

        //Создаем пользователей
        context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(
            "CREATE USER BakeryAdmin FOR LOGIN BakeryAdmin CREATE USER BakeryManager FOR LOGIN BakeryManager CREATE USER BakeryUser FOR LOGIN BakeryUser");

        //Создаем роли
        context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("CREATE ROLE Admins AUTHORIZATION db_accessadmin CREATE ROLE Managers AUTHORIZATION  db_datawriter CREATE ROLE Users AUTHORIZATION db_datareader");

        //Добавляем пользователей к ролям
        context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(
            "EXEC sp_addrolemember 'Admins', 'BakeryAdmin' EXEC sp_addrolemember 'Managers', 'BakeryManager' EXEC sp_addrolemember 'Users', 'BakeryUser'");
```

Естественно, что могу быть и другие пользователи, но роли останутся теже.
Собственно кратко вопросы:
Как передать в строку подключения логин/пароль?
Как получить роли пользователя?